# React: How to use received json data from firebase to make list of array?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

I want to make a list of user details by filling the form with name, email, designation, phone & image input field, I've saved the form data in an object and sent the form data to it's parent using props `addedUser(userData);`, I'm using this `addedUser` prop in the parent component to send the data to the firebase and then use the same fetched data to make a list of users in array.

I've made `loadedData` empty array simply wanna push the data into it but the `responseData.json()` doesn't give me anything, the data is being saved to firebase perfectly but I'm facing problems using it.

Please check the code here and also the `<Users />` component code where I'm trying to make the list:

Parent:-

```
function App() {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const responseData = await fetch(
                "https://react-users-db-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/users.json"
            );

            const data = responseData.json();
            console.log(data);

            const loadedData = [];

            for (const key in data) {
                loadedData.push({
                    key: key,
                    userName: data[key].userName,
                    userEmail: data[key].userEmail,
                    userDesignation: data[key].userDesignation,
                    usePhone: data[key].usePhone,
                    userImage: data[key].userImage,
                });
            }

            console.log(loadedData);

            setUserData(loadedData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchData]);

    async function recieveUserData(users) {
        const responseData = await fetch(
            "https://react-users-db-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/users.json",
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(users),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            }
        );
        const data = await responseData.json();
        console.log(data);
    }

    return (
        <main>
            <div className="form__wrap">
                <AddUserForm addedUser={recieveUserData} />
            </div>
            <div className="user__wrap">
                {userData.length > 0 ? (
                    <Users newUser={userData} />
                ) : (
                    <p>No user found</p>
                )}
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}
```

Users Component:

```
export default function Users({ newUser }) {
    console.log(newUser);
    return (
        <div className="usercard__wrap">
            {newUser.map((el, i) => {
                return (
                    <UserCard
                        key={i}
                        name={el.userName}
                        email={el.userEmail}
                        designation={el.userDesignation}
                        phone={el.userPhone}
                        image={el.userImage}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Data is going to firebase:-

[image]

But `responseData.json()` is giving me this, I can't see my user object to access:-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fetchData function you need to await responseData.json().

```
 const data = await responseData.json();
```

Comment: can you please tell me this  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73923906/react-how-to-display-fetched-data-immediately-after-form-submit