# React: How to display fetched data immediately after form submit?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

I've stored the form data in an object and sending this data through `props` using `addedUser(userData);` I've send a `POST` request to the firebase and then fetching the data to display the user's details in JSX, my `AddUserForm.js` have form and data sending to `App.js` for sending `POST` request, So how can I add my UserCard immediately right after form submission?

For now I'm reloading the page as the form submits, but I don't think that's the right way, right?

```
const onFormSubmit = () => {
     addedUser(userData);
     window.location.reload(true);
}
```

And I did this in my `App.js` to fetch and sending post request to firebase

```
function App() {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const responseData = await fetch(
                "https://react-users-db-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/users.json"
            );
            const data = await responseData.json();
            const loadedData = [];
            for (const key in data) {
                loadedData.push({
                    key: key,
                    userName: data[key].userName,
                    userEmail: data[key].userEmail,
                    userBio: data[key].userBio,
                    userGithub: data[key].userGithub,
                    userImage: data[key].userImage,
                });
            }
            setUserData(loadedData.reverse());
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchData]);

    async function recieveUserData(users) {
        const responseData = await fetch(
            "https://react-users-db-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/users.json",
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(users),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            }
        );
        const data = await responseData.json();
        console.log(data);
    }

    return (
        <main>
            <div className="form__wrap">
                <AddUserForm addedUser={recieveUserData} />
            </div>
            <div className="user__wrap">
                {userData.length > 0 ? (
                    <Users newUser={userData} />
                ) : (
                    <p>No user found</p>
                )}
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}
```

Comment: There should be no full page reload in react / SPA's tbh ... you can pass the data to your component as `props` ..

Comment: yes, so how can I display the fetched data immediately?

Comment: you have to pass as props and it does render it when data is available ... you mean after the response arrives or the same data that is being sent to server ?

Comment: can you please show me through code example?
Here is my updated repo code, you can check - https://github.com/mohitdevelops/user-entry/blob/main/src/App.js

Comment: I would personally use something like react query. It can simplify a lot of things, including what you're trying to achieve. Right after submitting the data, you could invalidate the original user fetch which would then re fetch it or just use some of the built in props like re fetch.

Answer (score 2):

A sample, on how I would do the same

- you can set the data coming from response if it is different from the data being sent and can also have a check if it has no error response from server too.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const submitHandler = () => {
    const fakeData = {
      userId: 1,
      id: 1,
      title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident oreprehenderit",
      body: "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur",
    };
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(fakeData),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(fakeData));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={submitHandler}> fake post </button>
      <hr></hr>
      {data && <Cards title={data.title} body={data.title} />}
    </div>
  );
};

const Cards = ({ title, body }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <p>{body}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `fetchData` at the bottom of `recieveUserData` function, just below the `const data = await responseData.json();` statement.